# How can I disable a link in the vue component?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, hyperlink, vuejs2, vue-component

My html like this :

```
<div id="app">
    <a class="btn btn-danger" href="javascript:" @click="add($event)">add</a>
</div>
```

My javascript like this :

```
var vue = new Vue({
    el: '#app',

    methods: {
        add(event) {
            event.target.disabled = true
        }
    }
});
```

Demo and full code like this : https://jsfiddle.net/q7xcbuxd/221/

I try like that. But if I click button add, it's not disabled

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since you are using boostrap, the proper way to disable a (anchor) button is not to set `.disabled = true`, but to **add a `disabled` class**.

Two other notes. You probably want to prevent the default behavior of the `click` event, so use `@click.prevent`. Also, if you don't have additional arguments, you don't need to use `="add($event)"`, just `="add"` will suffice.

Demo below:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  methods: {
    add(event) {
      event.target.className += ' disabled'
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body { padding: 10px }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="app">
  <a class="btn btn-danger" href="javascript:" @click.prevent="add">add</a>
</div>
```

You can also go *pure* Vue and use a class binding:

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: {
    btnDisabled: false
  },
  methods: {
    add(event) {
      this.btnDisabled = true; // mutate data and let vue disable the element
    }
  }
})
```

```css
body { padding: 10px }
```

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/vue"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div id="app">
  <a class="btn btn-danger" href="javascript:" @click.prevent="add" :class="{disabled: btnDisabled}">add</a>
</div>
```

Comment: I want to ask. If disable class like this : `event.target.className += ' disabled'`. How if I want to enable button?

Comment: You would do `event.target.className = event.target.className.replace(/\disabled\b/g, "");`. If you can ditch IE (or if you can add a [polyfill](https://github.com/yola/classlist-polyfill)), maybe using `classList` is a cleaner alternative:  `element.classList.add("disabled");` and `element.classList.remove("disabled");`

Answer (score 6):

Add an event to your element and preventDefault.

Then, add a custom css class that would grayed out the button and with disabled mouse cursor, and bind that class to your element.

**CSS:**

```
.disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  color: gray
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<a href=""  @click.prevent="add" :class="disabledClass" >Add</a>
```

**JS:**

```
computed: {
  disabledClass: () => {
    return isAddButtonDisabled ? "disabled" : ""
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

event.preventDefault() would disable it.

and [.prevent](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/events.html#Event-Modifiers) modifier allows you to add it easily

`@click.prevent="add($event)"`