# VUE: How to prevent next click with delay?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

How to after click prevent next click with 600ms delay? I want "disable" all this **a** tags for 600ms if I click on any of them. Im a little lost, thanks.

**VUE**

```
  <ul>
    <li v-for="item in navigation" :key="item" :title="item.name">
      <router-link :to="item.path" @click="delay()">{{ item.name }}</router-link>
    </li>
  </ul>
```

**delay()**

```
  methods: {
    delay() {
      this.event.preventDefault();
    }
  }
```

**EDIT**
so i did some changes. I Want make this:

After the button is clicked, each button will get attribute DISABLED for 600ms, then it will disappear and the button will work again. Do not count the router into this timer. I tried something like this, but the button is permanently disabled

```
<ul>
  <li v-for="item in navigation" :key="item" :title="item.name">
    <button type="button" disabled="false" @click="delay(item.path)">{{ item.name }}</button>
  </li>
</ul>
```

**method**

```
methods: {
  delay(to) {
    this.$router.push(to);
    setTimeout(() => this.disabled = true, 600)
  },
},
```

Answer (score 1):

My suggestion is to use the setTimeout to disable/enable the link, like this:

```
<a :disabled="!linkEnabled" href="javascript:void(0)" @click="delay(item.path)">{{ item.name }}</a>
```

then in your function:

```
delay(to) {
    this.linkEnable = false;
    this.$router.push(to);
    setTimeout(() => this.linkEnable = true, 600)
}
```

Comment: You have linkEnabled there and linkEnable in the code (without d). I fixed it but still this doesn't work at all.

Comment: I've found a question (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49504111/how-can-i-disable-a-link-in-the-vue-component) that uses a css class, like this: 
**:class="{disabled: btnDisabled}"**
and your css like this:
.disabled {
  cursor: not-allowed;
  color: gray
}

Comment: Have one on me, goal posts keep moving

Answer (score 0):

You can create router and use beforeEach to leasten router change and wait form some time

```
const routes = [{
    path: "/login",
    name: "Login Component",
    component: LoginComponent
}]
const router = new createRouter({
    history: createWebHistory(),
    routes,
});

router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
    // wait how mach you want then next('to your route')
}


export default router;
```

For more [Vue Router](https://router.vuejs.org/api/interfaces/Router.html#beforeeach)

Comment: I don't want the router with a delay, just add a delay to <a> so that I always have to wait 600ms before I can click again.